# how do you create sections and new lines in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am working on my first knitr document. I've made a lot of progress but, could figure out two things yet.

I am trying to do two things:

1. Insert section
2. insert new lines

I have this code to create section for each application, print heading, charts:

````
```{r qplot,fig.width=10, fig.height=8, message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap='long caption', fig.scap='short'}

library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
cat(paste("Application Name-", App))
cat("\n"
print(ggplot(data, aes(Date, cpu))+geom_line()
cat("\n")
```
````

I see that Application Name text is on the same line as the charts. cat("\n") does not seem be working. Also, how would I insert section in pdf so that if I click on a section, it will take to the correct section?

Comment: To what kind of document are you sending your output?  HTML?  PDF? Word?  Markdown?

Comment: @Benjamin, pdf document.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin tidy=FALSE did the trick for new line but I would I create sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

````
---
title: "My Report"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
---

# Application `r 1+1`

```{r qplot,fig.width=10, fig.height=8, message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap='long caption', fig.scap='short', tidy=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+geom_line()
```
````

Comment: I tried this: output: 
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: true
    highlight: zenburn, not working.

Comment: @user1471980 This should give you some output if copy/paste everything and save as `.Rmd` file. Spacing matters in the top part. Also, the top part is auto-generated by Rstudio if you change the settings.

Answer (score 2):

In general, with markdown documents, you insert a new section with

```
# Section Name
```

You can include more `#`'s to get a subsection, subsubsection, etc.

The markdown for a new line is two empty spaces at the end of a line.

See https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf for more on the markdown syntax.

If you want to put in section breaks and line breaks in the document, you need to send it with the `results='asis'` chunk option and `cat("...")` where the contents of `...` are in the language to which you are rendering.

Thus, if you are rendering to a PDF, you will use `cat("\\section{Section Name}")` to get a section break and `cat("\\newline")` to get a new line.

````
```{r qplot,fig.width=10, fig.height=8, message=FALSE, results = 'asis', echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.cap='long caption', fig.scap='short'}

library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
cat(paste("\\section{Application Name-", App, "}"))
print(ggplot(data, aes(Date, cpu))+geom_line()
cat("\\newline")
```
````